# Different cell height at runtime than in storyboard XCode9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

[image]

I've got a cell that I've made a subclass for and am setting up all the layout stuff in the storyboard. On runtime, the cells are way shorter than I have them set to be in the storyboard.

I'm getting a different background color and height in the simulator.

```
class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

func configureCell(profileImage : UIImage, email : String, content : String) {
    self.profileImage.image = profileImage
    self.emailLabel.text = email
    self.messageLabel.text = content
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
 }
```

That's the only code I've got in my subclass.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have constraints issue. Pls show us your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Set proper constraint to table cell and set table view dynamic height using `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight`

e.g.

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create self-sizing table view cell (dynamic row height), use proper constraints to define cell's size and set the below properties (*rowHeight*, *estimatedRowHeight*) inside `viewDidLoad` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130
}
```